# How to set cookies in nextjs

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, next.js

In my next.js project,I want to set cookies when user logs in. with `document.cookies(something)` it is setting cookies, but it is limiting to set only one cookie. If I give more than one cookie it is taking only the first element. In both cases I am not able to get cookie values in the pages.It is giving document is not defined error.I tried using

```
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie,
```

with this I am able to set and get cookies,I am not able to secure my cookies. It will be great if you can solve this or suggest me some methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using https://www.npmjs.com/package/nookies as it's kinda tricky to do manually.

Answer (score -2):

You can't use the secure flag when your app is running on `localhost` unless you are running the application on `https`. To test if the secure flag is working, deploy the application on production or testing environment.